# how to use a regex with grep/egrep to find all inner text of html tags and wrap them with a custom tag?

Tags: regex, grep

I am  using the grep command in the terminal to search for a regular expression pattern in a file that matches all inner text within any number of html tags, or react compnenets, for example:

```
<div ..any number of atrributes> 
    <Components ...attr>
        <...AnyNumbeTags> 
            MY Content
        <...AnyNumbeClosingTags>
    </Component>
</div>
```

The html could be formatted and indented with spaces.

I am using this command with a little but no much success:

```
grep -o '<[^>]*>[^<]*<\/[^>]*>' filename.js
```

Is there a more generic regex I could use to find all content of html?
The purpose is to find them all and wrap the result with a custom component.

Answer (score -1):

Using `awk`, you can get all text that are not within `<...>`

```
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]+>/,"");sub(/^ +/,"")} NF' file
MY Content
```

This will work on:

```
<div ..any number of atrributes> 
    <Components ...attr>
        <...AnyNumbeTags> 
            MY Content
        <...AnyNumbeClosingTags>
    </Component>
</div>
```

and

```
<div ..any number of atrributes>
    <Components ...attr>
        <...AnyNumbeTags> MY Content  <...AnyNumbeClosingTags>
    </Component>
</div>
```

`gsub(/<[^>]+>/,"")` removes all  block
`sub(/^ +/,"")` removes spaces before text at start of line
`NF` print only line that are not black (1 or more field)